# Users are getting logged out randomly in laravel

Tags: php, session, cookies, laravel, laravel-4

I currently have the problem, that my users are getting logged out randomly after a couple of minutes, regardless if they have set a remember-me cookie or not.

session.php:

```
'driver' => 'database',
'lifetime' => 240,
'expire_on_close' => false,
'cookie' => 'kurtsession',
'path' => '/',
'domain' => '.my-domain.com', // Domain edited for security reasons
```

phpinfo() says:

```
session.cache_expire 180
session.cookie_lifetime 0
session.gc_divisor 100
session.gc_maxlifetime 1440
session.gc_probability 1
```

UserController.php

```
public function do_login()
    {
        $input = array(
            'email'    => Input::get( 'email' ), // May be the username too
            'username' => Input::get( 'email' ), // so we have to pass both
            'password' => Input::get( 'password' ),
            'remember' => Input::get( 'remember' ),
        );


        // If you wish to only allow login from confirmed users, call logAttempt
        // with the second parameter as true.
        // logAttempt will check if the 'email' perhaps is the username.
        if ( Confide::logAttempt( $input, true ) ) 
        {
            // If the session 'loginRedirect' is set, then redirect
            // to that route. Otherwise redirect to '/'
            $r = Session::get('loginRedirect');
            if (!empty($r))
            {
                Session::forget('loginRedirect');
                return Redirect::to($r);
            }

            return Redirect::to('/'); // change it to '/admin', '/dashboard' or something
        }
        else
        {
            $user = new User;

            // Check if there was too many login attempts
            if( Confide::isThrottled( $input ) )
            {
                $err_msg = Lang::get('confide.alerts.too_many_attempts');
            }
            elseif( $user->checkUserExists( $input ) and ! $user->isConfirmed( $input ) )
            {
                $err_msg = Lang::get('confide.alerts.not_confirmed');
            }
            else
            {
                $err_msg = Lang::get('confide.alerts.wrong_credentials');
            }

            return Redirect::action('UserController@login')
                ->withInput(Input::except('password'))
                ->with( 'error', $err_msg );
        }
    }
```

I also checked the server timezone (ssh -> date is correct CEST and date -u is UTC).

I don't know what is going wrong and I don't know how to debug this.

So if you have any hints, please reply.

Thanks!

Comment: what version of laravel are you using?

Comment: I am using 4.1. Sorry, forgot to mention that!

Comment: Show your `Auth::attempt()` code for logging in a user.

Comment: I am using Confide for user management. I added the code to the original post.